# Is $\mathbb{Z}_p[\mathbb{Z}_p]$ a PID?

Tags: abstract-algebra, principal-ideal-domains, group-rings

> Is $\mathbb{Z}_{p}[G]$ a PID, where $G=(\mathbb{Z}_{p},+)$ is the additive group of the $p$-adics $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$?

I am studying a paper where the authors implicitly use that claim, but it is unclear to me. (I am a little bit embarassed by the fact that I cannot solve this myself.)

Comment: What does the notation $\mathbb{Z}[\mathbb{Z}]$ stand for?

Comment: What's $\Bbb Z[\Bbb Z]$?

Comment: Do you mean the group ring whose basis elements are elements of $\mathbb{Z}$?  In other words, the ring where the elements are finite sums of the form $\sum n_i e_{m_i}$ with $n_i,m_i\in\mathbb{Z}$ and multiplication defined as $(n_1 e_{m_1})\cdot (n_2 e_{m_2})=(n_1n_2)e_{m_1+m_2}$?

Comment: What is $\mathbb{Z}[\mathbb{Z}$? If you mistyped  $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ check out Gaussian integers.

Comment: Sorry, stupid typo.

Comment: By $\mathbb{Z}_p$ do you mean the $p$-adics or integers mod $p$?

Comment: @Eric Wofsey: $p$-adics.

Comment: put $g=1$ then $(1+g+g^{2}+\ldots+g^{p-1})$ is  a nilpotent element of order 2.. hence your group ring is  not an integral domain.

Comment: In the above i considered G as a multiplicatiov group not  an additive group, while it s  an abelian group!

Comment: In general, when you use $\mathbb Z_p$ to mean $p$-adics, put it in the question, because it is quite commonly the notation for $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$, too.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1691808/is-mathbbz-mathbbz-p-a-pid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't true; in fact, $\mathbb{Z}_p[G]$ is not even Noetherian.  For instance, take the augmentation ideal $I$, i.e. the ideal generated by $\{g-1:g\in G\}$.  If $I$ were finitely generated, there would be a finite subset $F\subset G$ such that $I$ is generated by the elements $g-1$ for $g\in F$.  But if $H\subseteq G$ is the subgroup generated by $F$ and $J$ is the ideal generated by the elements $g-1$ for $g\in F$, it is easy to see that the canonical quotient map $\mathbb{Z}_p[G]\to\mathbb{Z}_p[G/H]$ factors through the quotient $\mathbb{Z}_p[G]\to\mathbb{Z}_p[G]/J$.  Thus if $J$ is all of $I$, $H$ must be all of $G$.  But $G$ is not finitely generated, so this is impossible.